# Change the folder that Windows Explorer starts at

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows7, when you open the Windows Explorer using the pinned Windows Explorer button on taskbar, it opens WE and points it to My Documents folder.

Is there a way to change this so it doesn't open My Documents, but rather "Computer" just as <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut does?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the method that used to work in XP and Vista?:

> - Open Explorer, and go to your Start Menu folder.
> - Find the shortcut for Explorer, right click on it, and select Properties.
> - Click on the Shortcut tab, and change the Target so it reads: c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n, /e, d:\myfolder (where c:\windows is your Windows directory, and d:\myfolder is the directory in which you want Explorer to start.)

From [Easy Tweaks](http://www.easytweaks.com/2007/05/07/change-startup-folder-vista/) (Vista)

On my XP machine I have "Start in" set to "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" which opens Explorer in My Computer from where I can see all the drives etc.

**NOTE *I haven't got Windows-7 to check this, but I thought it ought to be mentioned***

Comment: The problem is that I don't want it to start in a folder, but rather in "Computer", so my disks are shown. For now, this will do, but I wonder what should I write there to get to the Computer (virtual) folder

Comment: Ah - sorry, missed that bit of your question.

Comment: Does work under 7, ChrisF. No worries. I'd just change "c:\windows\" to "%windir%\"

Comment: No longer works on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

This would be the target line to open Windows Explorer with 'My Computer':

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}
```

Comment: this was (and still is) the correct answer for Windows XP.  Still using it for win 10. (although win 10 allows you to leave out the /e, and stil get the two-pane classic explorer window)

Answer (score 2):

```
%windir%\explorer.exe /n, /e, /select, C:\
```

The above selects the `C:\` drive, but it does not open it, effectively making *Computer* your selected folder on the left pane.

Enjoy :)

It is not meant to ignore other answers that already addressed it. My vote goes to them. But I prefer human-readable stuff to abstract things like *::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}*.

Comment: No longer works on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it from "Quick Access" to "My Computer" there is a much simpler solution found by @scott-hanselman.

Windows Explorer > View > Options > General > Open File Explorer to: [choose]

Source: https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/631287927184621568

Answer (score 0):

Nothing but a workaround trick (For Windows 10, should work from Windows 8 I think):

- First Right-click the folder you want to make default > Hover on Send To > Click Desktop (Create Shortcut).
- Open `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` folder.
- Move the shortcut which has been created in Desktop to the folder.
- Delete existing shortcut named `File Explorer`.
- Rename the newly moved shortcut to `File Explorer`.

It will only work if explorer was opened from pinned shortcut in Taskbar.