# Set Windows Explorer start folder to sub-folder of Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts

How can I set the start folder in the Windows Explorer to a sub-folder of the Desktop?

I know this has been asked in a subtlely different way before ([Change the folder that Windows Explorer starts at](https://superuser.com/questions/49226/change-the-folder-that-windows-explorer-starts-at)), but a problem arises if one wants to open a folder that is on the desktop.

What I am doing currently is:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,/n,Desktop\Folder
```

But it redirects me to

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Desktop\Folder"
```

as a subfolder of c:\

How it looks in the explorer:

```
Desktop
 |->My Documents
 |->My Computer
 | |->c:\
 |     |->Documents and Settings
 |        |-><username>
 |           |->Desktop
 |              |->Folder *Shortcut puts me here*
 |->Recycle Bin
 |->Folder *I want to be here*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Btw: I have both looked for CLSID for the Desktop directly and using a CLSID for `My Computer` and doing `../Folder`. doesn't work.

Comment: What I tried: Making a Shortcut of target type "Folder". This allows linking to the Folder directly on the Desktop, but the Explorer Bar showing the folder tree (/e) is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome! Found it in this article at TechNet: [Windows Explorer Folders](http://blogs.technet.com/jroller/archive/2004/07/06/174444.aspx)

1. In the Windows Explorer go to `Tools -> Folder Options -> File Types`
2. Select `Folder` and click `Advanced`
3. Select `explore` and click `Set Default`

From now on all Shortcuts you create by dragging a folder will start with the folder tree showing!

Creating a short-cut to "Desktop\Folder" will now work as I want it.

Added benefit: Opening `My Computer` will now also show the folder tree by default!

Comment: If this answers your original question to your satisfaction, you might want to accept it.

Comment: Yes, but I need to wait two days to do so. I am new to SuperUser (after some time on SO) and surprised that it is harder to ask a question worth an up-vote.