# Have Windows Explorer open to specific folder

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the folder that Windows Explorer starts at](https://superuser.com/questions/49226/change-the-folder-that-windows-explorer-starts-at)

Is there a way to configure what folder Windows Explorer opens to when it launches, when right clicking the Start menu and choosing Explore?  If so, how can that be done?

Comment: How do you launch it?

Comment: +1 to @Dennis.  We need a *lot* more meat to this question.  Otherwise, you're just begging for a walkthrough on how to create folder shortcuts on your Desktop.

Comment: Duplicate of [Change the folder that Windows Explorer starts at](http://superuser.com/q/49226/97028).

Comment: @Dennis normally by right clicking "Start" menu, and choosing "Explore"

Comment: @CharlieRB, this is for Windows XP

Comment: You are correct. The question was related to Win 7, but there is an [answer](http://superuser.com/a/49229/97028) for Windows XP if you scroll down. Sorry I did not make that clear when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the command lines switches for explorer in Windows XP just there:

[Explorer.exe Command-Line Options for Windows XP MSKB 314853](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853)