# Is there a way to make Windows Explorer open without expanding the first drive contents?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I have multiple drives and partitions on my machine and I find it annoying that explorer has to start with the first drive expanded.  I know it's a minor thing but I would like to know if there is any setting in registry, group policy or explorer itself that will cause it to open with all folders closed?

Comment: If you set it to open at My Computer as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/49235/138343), does that help?

Comment: Seems like that could be done for a shortcut but probably not as standard behavior for explorer.

Answer (score 0):

cant tell you if this will solve your problem but i have tested it out for myself and it works on my machine.but you might have a setting checked in the options in explorer.

go to tools/ folder options. at the bottom of the window. make sure the "Automatically expand to current folder is unchecked". That will disable the auto expand of the viewing folder. But if you have it expanded windows remembers your last expanded folder.

also go to tools/ folder options/view tab. in advanced settings uncheck "uncheck Display Simple folder view in Explorers folder list".

Then restart your explorer. should be fixed now.

Hope this helps work on 2 of my machines windows xp x64 / windows 7 premium x64.

Comment: I don't seem to have that option under Folder Options.  Are you using XP?

Comment: yeah im using 64 bit version. also go to tools/ folder options/view tab. in advanced settings uncheck "uncheck Display Simple folder view in Explorers folder list".

Comment: You have this at least ill screen cap mine for ya and link the image. **also go to tools/ folder options/view tab. in advanced settings uncheck "uncheck Display Simple folder view in Explorers folder list".**

Comment: ok i found this for you might make it a little more easier if you cant find the settings in folder options. this link says similar to what i said plus explains how to do it in the regedit as well.                                                                                                                                   [link] (http://www.watchingthenet.com/stop-windows-explorer-from-automatically-expanding-folders-trees-in-xp.html)