# Start Windows Explorer in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, shortcuts

When I use the key combination <kbd>Windows+E</kbd>, Explorer loads with `My Computer` selected (showing the list of drives on my system). Good, this is the functionality I want.

However, when I click either the:

- `Windows Explorer` shortcut on my `Quick Launch` toolbar
- Start > Programs > Accessories > Windows Explorer shortcut

then Explorer displays with `My Documents` selected.

On checking the properties of either shortcut, I noticed `Start in` was set to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. Aha! I thought, I'll change that to `C:\` or `%SystemDrive%` (which I confirmed from the command-line is set to `C:\`)...but neither help. Explorer always loads with `My Documents` selected when launched via shortcut.

How do I get the `Windows Explorer` shortcut to always start off in `My Computer`?

[image: Explorer showing My Documents...but I want My Computer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later I stumbled across [this related superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/49226). After following the advice and links contained therein, I finally got it working. Here are the steps:

- Right-click the shortcut and select `Properties`
- Clear the text in the `Start in` box (ie. leave it blank)
- Set `Target` as below

To show the `Folders` navigation pane:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe /n,/e,/select,%SystemDrive%
```

To only select the root of `My Computer`:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe /n,/select,%SystemDrive%
```

More details can be found [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2863-windows-explorer-taskbar-icon-change-open-target.html) which gives many examples of selecting different files and folders.