# Windows Explorer - when going to Desktop, don't select "Computer"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I use the <kbd>WIN+E</kbd> shortcut frequently to open Windows Explorer.  Whenever I click the "Desktop" folder via Favorites, it *always* selects "Computer", which when sorted by Date Modified, is always near the bottom.

This makes me then have to scroll up every time to go to my most recent documents.

[image]

Can I just get it to open and either not select any specific file/folder, or at least select the file/folder that's at the "top"?

(Note: Unless I'm misreading, this is a slightly different question than [Change the folder that Windows Explorer starts at](https://superuser.com/q/49226/529100))

Edit: To clarify, I'm not trying to get a new way to open Explorer.  I can do that in any way, using WIN+E, typing "explorer", opening my taskbar link to the Windows Explorer, etc.  *When it's already open* and I click "Desktop", it always selects "Computer" (or sometimes "Libraries").  As you can see in my screenshot, this then forces me to scroll up (or press <kbd>HOME</kbd>).  I just want it to open Desktop focused already at the top of the window.

Answer (score 1):

To get direct access to `Recent Places`, you could:

- Open 'Computer'.
- Right click on 'Recent Places'
- Choose 'Send To' > 'Desktop (create shortcut)'
- Optional: right click and edit properties to assign a key combination like
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to this icon

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - It's not necessarily the "Recent Places" I'm trying to get to.  It's when I click the "Desktop" (in my screen shot, it's under "Favorites"), it shows me the files, but *always* selects "Computer" by default, so I have to always scroll all the way up to go to the most recently modified file.  I'm trying to get it to just open the Desktop without selecting any folder/icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I was reading too fast. Please forgive me.

Here is my revised offering:

If you type "Desktop" in the Search field, a menu list pops up with "Desktop". You can select it there...after you forgive me.

[Screenshot here...](https://sta.sh/01dbv4vefchr)

Comment: The question asks how to **avoid** "Computer" being selected.

Comment: Yes, I know about typing "Win".  My question isn't how to open the Explorer in various ways, but specifically when I click "Desktop", it always selects "Computer", and I just want it to select nothing.  I'll try to edit my OP with a more clear idea of what I'm trying for.

Comment: changed...people can change!